# geological visualisations in blender

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I am looking for some assistance in creating some geologcial folding animation in blender. I have created a 3 layered version with 2  episodes of folding (the first set of pics) with a bit of weathering to remove the peaks at the end of the animation.
 However this is way to simple as rock layers generally act differently from each other some will be more fluid while others will break rather than buckle. The process i am trying to simulate is better represented in the the second video which itself is a sand box simulation(frames from a youtube video). So my question is  are there any simulation/physics tools that can help me to create this simulation. I used a lattice and shape keys to create the animation. I see lots of tutorials about bouncing balls but nothing where there tightly interlaced layers   cheers and thanks sally
 [image: blenderfolds]

[image: sandboxfolds]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYra6RwovKc